# What is the cut off frequency of the RC filter in this circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, filter, active-filter

I have the circuit of a heartbeat sensor  module from pulsesensor.com but I can't seem to understand  the kind of filter in the schematic.  They Said  it contains a low pass RC  filter  with R = 100 ohm and C = 47uF. But from my analysis I see a hpf. What kind of  filter is formed  by R2, C2, C1, C3 and C4. what is the cut off frequency of the filter. 
[image: schematic]

Comment: Why don't you contact them for clarification?

Comment: There are no components marked 100 Ω or 47 µF in your schematic. I don't think we can help.

Comment: @Transistor I mean. What  kind of  filter  is formed by R2, C2, C1, C3 and C4

Comment: Well edit your question and ask that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They Said it contains a low pass RC filter with R = 100 ohm and C =
>   47uF.

No, they [said](http://pulsesensor.com/pages/open-hardware):-

> we designed a fairly universal Low Pass Filter for the output (passive
>   RC. R: 100 C: 4.7uF)

but...

> We made **some changes** to the original Pulse Sensor circuit

There are two filter stages in this circuit. The first is a passive low-pass filter formed by R2 and C2/C1. It has a cutoff frequency of ~5.64Hz and stop-band attenuation of 20dB per decade. However the load impedance in combination with R2 and C2 will form a high pass filter, so the practical result is a *band-pass* filter.

(Note: the 14K resistor in the simulation below is a simplification of the complex load impedance in your circuit).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzxOFI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The second stage (C3, C4, U2 etc.) is an active band-pass filter with gain. In isolation it would have 47dB gain at a center frequency of about 2.3Hz, but with the two stages combined the overall result is 37.5dB gain at a center frequency of about 2.6Hz.

Analyzing a multistage filter circuit like this is not easy, due to the complex interaction between stages. Rather than trying to do the calculations by hand I simulated your circuit in [LTspice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/#LTspice). Here's the  schematic:-

[image]